# ArcGIS Surface Length Tool equivalent in FME?

Tags: fme-form, 3d, length

I am trying to calculate the 3D length of a line.

I currently have a rather complex and cumbersome model built in ArcGIS ModelBuilder that uses a tool called "Surface Length".

I was wondering if there is an equivalent tool in FME?

Ultimately I want to calculate the 3D length of a shapefile. I have DEM data for the same area.

Comment: Don't have access to FME right now, but if your line is ZM, then there should be a build in method you can expose that will give you the length I bet. Maybe Mark Ireland will pick this thread up and hook you up.

Comment: ZM? The line doesn't have any Z values of its own, although I do have DEM data. The LengthCalculator transformer seems to be close, but I'm not sure how to get Z values into it.

Answer (score 4):

**Let's first address the side note.**  "3D length" means the actual length of the path on the earth's surface represented by the polyline, accounting for the additional length contributed by its motion up and down.  "Geodesic length" usually refers to the length of a path within a [Riemannian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold).  There are at least two useful and reasonable ways in which the earth is viewed as such a manifold.  The more conventional one uses the *ellipsoidal model*.  In this model, elevation is ignored, "straight" means "moving along the ellipsoid without any sideways acceleration," and distance is computed by dividing the path into a sequence of very small straight segments.  From this point of view 3D distance and geodesic distance usually differ.

A less conventional viewpoint is that the earth's topographic surface is the manifold.  Now the 3D distance and geodesic distance almost coincide.  A tiny quibble is that lines that appear to be straight on the map (or even on the ellipsoid) usually will *not* be straight on the earth's surface.  This leads to such a small error, though, that for most purposes you can safely consider the 3D length to be geodesic in this sense.

Now, about **computing that 3D length**.  When you account for elevation, each segment of the polyline is really (assumed to be) the hypotenuse of a triangle.  The length on the map, *dx*, is the length of the triangle's base; the difference in elevations between endpoints, *dz*, is the length of the triangle's height (its "rise"); and the 3D length is the length of the hypotenuse, *l*.  The Pythagorean Theorem tells us that

(1)  *l*  = Sqrt( *dx*^2 + *dz*^2 ).

Therefore, by breaking any polyline into its constituent segments and computing *l* for each segment, you can obtain the 3D length by summing the results.

*dx* is just the length (on the map) of the polyline segment; there are many ways to compute it in ArcGIS.  Pick your favorite.

Computing *dz* accurately can be done in several ways.  The best perhaps is to find the coordinates of the endpoints of each segment and use them to extract the DEM's elevation.  This would require a bit of scripting in ArcGIS.  A more straightforward method (for non self intersecting polylines) is to obtain a *zonal range* of the DEM using the segments as the zones.  In principle, the segments should be so short that when lifted to the earth's surface they still are fairly straight.  Thus, the zonal range should be the difference in elevations at the endpoints.  There's a bit of bias in this approach, though, because any two successive segments share a common node.  The elevation of that node will be assigned to the range of one or the other, but not both, of the segments attached to that node.  This systematically shrinks the estimated ranges.  You could correct for this by multiplying the zonal range (let's call it *r*) by (*l* + *c*)/*l* where *c* is the cellsize; that is,

(2) *dz* = *r* (*l* + *c*) / *l*.

This extrapolates the zonal range to the full range of each segment: its rise.

The mechanics of this operation in ArcGIS are:

1. Break the polyline into individual segments, each with a unique ID.
2. Obtain the zonal range of the DEM based on the segments layer.
3. Join the ranges to the segment layer attribute table.  Let's call this field [r].
4. Calculate the length [l] of each segment.
5. Calculate the rise via equation (2) above.
6. Calculate the 3D length via equation (1) above.
7. Sum the 3D lengths.

Perhaps this is a little less "cumbersome and complex" than the model currently used.

---

I should mention there are other approaches.  One of them involves computing the bearing of the polyline at each segment.  This can be combined with the slope and aspect grids (derived directly from the DEM) to compute the 3D length.  What is noteworthy about this strategy is that you can avoid dissecting the polyline into short segments and that all the operations are performed entirely on grids.  That would make it a good solution in raster-only GIS settings.

Answer (score 1):

Length Calculator with 3D.

http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/LengthCalculator but with the 3D option [image]

Comment: I was trying to use this transformer, but where do the Z values come from for it? Are they suposed to be in the input data itself? In which case how would that be stored? For example, I am inputing a line shapefile - where does the z data come from that is used to calculate the length from one vertex to another? I feel like the length calculator should be using another input to get elevation numbers because I don't see how the line shapefile can hold them.

Comment: added image with Length Dimension parameter for 3D lengths

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the transformer descriptions.
[Transformers](http://downloads.safe.com/fme/brochures/transformers.pdf)

Try the 3DInterpolator